# Testing a used car: steering is not 100% light

Tags: power-steering, steering, steering-wheel

A very newbie driver here.
The only car that I tried was the car I used in the driving lessons. It was a Golf 2013.
Today, I tried the first car and it is a Mercedes Benz C200 (it has power steering).
I noticed that the steering wheel is not as light as the Golf I used in my training lessons. The wheel of the Mercedes is not bad at all, but is a little bit heavier particularly after the second roll of the steering.

Is that normal, or there is something wrong in the Mercedes?

Comment: By "heavier" do you mean harder to turn?  Because that sounds totally normal.  The Ford van and Nissan Altima I learned to drive in felt different than my current car or most other cars I've owned or driven.

Comment: Yes, by heavy i mean hard when turning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be describing the *weight* of the steering, which varies from vehicle to vehicle.

It isn't something to be concerned about.

Many factors influence the lightness (or heaviness) of steering feel, including:

- steering/chassis geometry
- amount of hydraulic (power-steering) assist
- tire size

---

I would be concerned if you cannot or struggle to turn the wheel with the car stationary, because this indicates that the power-steering system is not helping you when it should.